# Why Does .NET Generate Escape Characters Within Hashed Password?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using SHA256 to hash the password before saving it to the DB.

```
    public string Hashpsw(string plainText)
    {
        String hash = "";
        try {
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);
            data = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(data);
            hash = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
        }
        catch 
        {
            //handle error
        }
        return hash;
    }
```

In the Entity Framework Core 3.1 controller, the context loads the password diferently, and the diference is escape characters:

```
string hashedPsw = Hashpsw(temp.Pass);
var _user=  _context.User.FirstOrDefault();// I was trying to mach psw using .Where(u => u.Login.Equals(temp.Login) && u.Pass.Equals(hashedPsw)) but failed due to this issue.
```

The password stored in the DB is `?e?Y B/?A~Hg??O??J\u001f??\u001f?~??????z?`, while the one in the _user object brought by .NET is `?e?Y B/?A~Hg??O??J\\u001f??\\u001f?~??????z?`.

How to prevent this behaviour?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Turning any old binary data into text is dangerous. Look at http://www.asciitable.com/ -- there are all sorts of control characters down at the lower end, which won't be rendered properly. With Unicode encodings, lots of byte sequences simply aren't valid, and will be replaced with a fallback character (or cause an exception). Use a suitable encoding to turn your binary data into text, such as hex, base64, etc.

Comment: @canton7 Thank you, so I should use a different hashing method, any recommended threads?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/376335/debugger-shows-double-backslash-instead-of-one.html

Comment: `Covert.ToBase64String`?

Comment: @TiyebM what you did is try to convert 8-bit bytes into 7-bit US-ASCII characters. By definition, this will mangle half the bytes. As for the name `hashpswd` I hope you don't use that code for password hashing because it's trivial to break. Passwords need to be *salted* before they're hashed (for at least 1000 times). Otherwise, it's trivial to recover the password using brute force - just calculate hashes for every password combination and check whether it matches the hash. Check Troy Hunt's [Our password hashing has no clothes](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hashpswd is a local variable for the result of the method, I updated to show that. Thank you.

Comment: @TiyebM there's *no* reason to write your own password hashing code either. For starters, .NET authentication providers already implement strong cryptographic password hashing for storage in a database. Second, the framework itself has the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netcore-3.1) that uses appropriate algorithms and at least 1000 iterations